Dos2Unix using UltraEdit?
Is there a way to convert line ending from Dos to Unix and vice versa in UltraEdit?
Notepad++ has this functionality built in using "Edit > EOL conversion"
My organization restricts the use of NPP So I'm stuck with UltraEdit
This document talks about such option
https://wiki.ultraedit.com/Converting_line_terminators


I am not an UltraEdit user; I am only looking at the website for the product. However, in discussing the full features of the product, it notes that you can use the special characters ^n for *ix EOL and ^p for DOSWin EOL, so implicitly if you search for ^n and replace with ^p (or vice-versa), you should accomplish what you want.
